# C++ Callback function pointer

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-x, objective-c++

i'm trying to create a callback function in Cocos2d-X. I have a singleton class (AdsMgr). In the AdsMgr, i want to store the function pointer. How should i replace the callBackPauseResume with the passing in parameter?

**AdsMgr.h**

```
class AdsMgr
{
private:
    static bool isAdsEnabled();

public:
    static void(*callBackPauseResume)(int index);
    static void initAds(void(*incallback)(int index));
}
```

**AdsMgr.mm**

```
void AdsMgr::initAds(void(*incallback)(int index))
{
    callBackPauseResume = incallback;

//    incallback(1);
}
```

**MainScene.cpp**

```
if(btn4 && btn4->getBoundingBox().containsPoint(location))
{            
     CCLOG("SHOW INTERSTITIAL");
     AdsMgr::initAds(MainScene::pauseResumeDuringAds);
}

void MainScene::pauseResumeDuringAds(int inFlag)
{
    switch (inFlag) {
        case 0:
        // Pause game
            break;
        case 1:
            // Resume Game
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I'm unable to compile and encountered the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "AdsMgr::callBackPauseResume", referenced from:
      AdsMgr::initAds(void (*)(int)) in AdsMgr.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, can you elaborate? Specifically, I can't make any sense out of your last sentence.

Comment: I'm trying to callBackPauseResume with the passing in incallback so in my other method, i'm able to call the MainScene::pauseResumeDuringAds function. Trying to make incallback as global

Comment: Okay, so what's the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "AdsMgr::callBackPauseResume", referenced from:
      AdsMgr::initAds(void (*)(int)) in AdsMgr.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Please paste it to your post. It's an essential part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your compile error, you haven't defined your `callBackPauseResume` variable. That's what the error is saying.

In addition to its declaration inside the class, you also need to add a definition for it, outside the class, in `AdsMgr.mm`:

```
void (*AdsMgr::callBackPauseResume)(int) = nullptr;
```